# Sorting NSMutableDictionary of ints in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, integer, nsmutabledictionary

I am just wondering if it is possible to sort a dictionary of integers in iOS?
Looking at previous examples/questions it seems that most people are sorting arrays of ints or arrays of dictionaries (containing ints).

However, lets say I have a dictionary with the structure:

```
 {numWords = 12, numPhotos = 15, numFriends = 8}
```

The keys are not the same so it seems I cannot use a sort descriptor (initialising with key), so is there any way to sort the integers and keep the associated keys in-tact?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558639/sort-an-nsmutabledictionary

Comment: dictionaries don't contain `int`s, they contain objects, perhaps `NSNumber`s

Comment: dictionaries are not ordered. How can you sort something that has no order at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort NSMutableDictionary keys by object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6956277)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort NSMutableDictionary keys by object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956277/sort-nsmutabledictionary-keys-by-object)

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries can't be sorted. But there is a method that will return an array of keys in order based on the values being sorted.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = ...; // your dictionary
NSArray *orderedKeys = [dict keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

In your case, `orderedKeys` would be `numFriends, numWords, numPhotos`.

To make use of the ordered keys you can do something like:

```
for (id key in orderedKeys) {
    id value = [dict objectForKey:key];
}
```

Comment: But with this solution, the returned array has no pointer from each integer to each string (which in this example renders the array useless or at least confusing)

Comment: @Da49 You can have two arrays sorted in parallel - see my answer.

Comment: @Da49 You can then iterate through the ordered keys and get the corresponding value. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary are not ordered. And you never sort dictionary.

Indeed you sort keys and or values.

For your case:

You need to extract all the values into arrayValues parallely keys in arraykeys, sort based on arrayValues.

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], [NSNumber numberWithInt:3], [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], [NSNumber numberWithInt:4], [NSNumber numberWithInt:6], nil];
NSMutableArray *arrayKeys = @[@"Five", @"Three", @"One", @"Two", @"Four", @"Six"];
NSMutableArray *arrayValues = @[@"Cinq", @"Trois", @"Un", @"Deux", @"Quatre", @"Six"];
 [array1 sortArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:) withPairedMutableArrays:arrayKeys, arrayValues, nil];
```

After the call to sortArrayUsingSelector:withPairedArrays:, the three arrays will all be in numeric order, so arrayKeys will look like this:

```
One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six
```

and arrayValues will look like this:

```
Un, Deux, Trois, Quatre, Cinq, Six
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the objects are unique:

1) ask the dictionary for the array of **allValues**

2) sort the array of values

3) since there is no **valueForKey**, for each value, use fast enumeration or **enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:** to find the appropriate key.

Answer (score 0):

**Dictionaries are not sortable.**

That said, you can have two sorted arrays, the one containing the keys and the other containing the associated values. Sort those by the ordering of the values.

```
NSDictionary *d = @{
    @"numWords": @12,
    @"numPhotos": @15,
    @"numFriends": @8
};

NSComparisonResult (^cmp)(id, id) = ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}

NSArray *keys = [d keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:cmp]
NSMutableArray *vals = [[id allValues] mutableCopy];
[vals sortUsingComparator:cmp];
```